# Why does the output seem rotated?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm wanting to create a 2D pixel like platformer using pygame and I've stumbled across this issue where the output seems to be rotated from what the pixel array shows. Could anyone explain why it seems rotated?

I have this array that is basically like a level designer where each digit represents a different pixel on the game.

```py
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

I also have this function that loops through each row and in that row each digit and gets the value and creates a rectangle with the color for the corresponding color for that digit at the specific index.

```py
color = (0, 0, 0)
for x in range(len(level)):
    for y in range(len(level[x])):
        value = level[x][y]
        if value == 1:
            color = (255, 255, 255)
        elif value == 0:
            color = (0, 0, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, color, (x * BLOCK_SIZE, y * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
```

and the output is this
[image]

but you can cleary see that the 1's in the array are in the same row not stacked on eachother...

can anyone explain?

Comment: `level` keeps data as `(row, column)` which means `(y,x)` but you use it as `(x,y)`

Comment: now it feels so obvious i feel unsmort

Comment: it is common mistake - we learn to plot graphs as `(x,y)` and we describe position on screen as `(x,y)` so we fogot that 2D list/array/matrix uses `(row, column)` which meas `(y,x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axis are inverted so instead of x, y like a normal plain, it is y, x and that is why it it looks rotated.